# How do I upgrade Angular from Version 12 to Version 16?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, package.json

I'm trying to upgrade the angular version of my app but encountering issues. Below are my app details

```
Angular :v12.2.17
node    :v14.18.3
npm     :6.14.15
```

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "My Application",
  "version": "12.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "apv": "ncu /^@app.*$/ -u --target patch",
    "test": "ng test",
    "ngcc": "ngcc",
    "versionFile": "gradle versionFile"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/localize": "^12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.3",
    "@circlon/angular-tree-component": "9.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "0.8.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "1.2.28",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "5.15.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "9.1.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "6.1.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "6.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "fuzzysort": "^1.1.4",
    "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.21.0",
    "ngx-awesome-uploader": "^13.0.1",
    "ngx-filesaver": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
    "ngx-monaco-editor": "^12.0.0",
    "ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
    "nl2br-pipe": "1.2.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.6",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "unist-builder": "^3.0.0",
    "unist-util-remove": "^3.1.0",
    "unist-util-visit": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4",
    "fuse.js": "^6.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ngrx/effects": "12.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "12.4.0",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "12.4.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "12.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "12.2.9",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1202.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "12.2.3",
    "ngx-toastr": "^13.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "12.2.3",
    "@ngrx/schematics": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "concurrently": "6.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.0-alpha",
    "ng-openapi-gen": "^0.17.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "12.2.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3",
    "xng-breadcrumb": "^6.7.0",
    "license-checker": "20.1.0"
  }
}
```

Here are the things I've tried as directed by the official [Angular Update page](https://update.angular.io/?v=12.0-16.0)

1. I originally installed the Node v16.20.2. And the npm is v8.19.4
2. I had run the command `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13`

Below are the errors which are encounterd.

```
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "13.4.0").
                  Package "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "13.4.0").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "13.4.0").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/localize" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "13.4.0").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\pjangti\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-9hw6sz\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

**Also I have referred all the related questions and tried below steps**

- Used --force but found the same result
- Also used --legacy-peer-deps but no change in the result
- Then I have tried updating @angular/common, @angular/core, @angular/forms, angular/localize to "13.4.0" in package.json and did ng update and got suggestion as below

```
 Name                                 Version                  Command to update
     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      @angular/cdk                         12.2.9 -> 13.3.9         ng update @angular/cdk@13
      @angular/cli                         12.2.3 -> 13.3.9         ng update @angular/cli@13
      @angular/core                        12.2.17 -> 13.4.0        ng update @angular/core@13
      @angular/material                    12.2.9 -> 13.3.9         ng update @angular/material@13
      @ngrx/store                          12.4.0 -> 16.2.0         ng update @ngrx/store
      ngx-build-plus                       12.2.0 -> 16.0.0         ng update ngx-build-plus
      ngx-toastr                           13.2.1 -> 17.0.2         ng update ngx-toastr
```

- As per the suggestion I tried running ng update one by one and started with `ng update @angular/cdk@13` but encountered with below issues

```
Fetching dependency metadata from registry...
                  Package "@angular/material" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cdk" (requires "12.2.9", would install "13.3.9").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/compiler-cli" (requires "^12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires "~4.2.3 || ~4.3.2", would install "4.8.4").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@ngrx/effects" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires "^12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires "^11.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@angular-devkit/build-angular" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/localize" (requires "^12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@tolerant/common-components" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser" (requires "12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@tolerant/common-components" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" (requires "12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
                  Package "@tolerant/common-components" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/router" (requires "12.0.0" (extended), would install "14.3.0").
× Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "C:\Users\pjangti\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-fp0OkY\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

- I have tried to run all the commands together suggested in "command to update" but again the migration failed.

*Appreciate the suggestions/inputs on this*

Comment: When you upgrade look in all your 3rd party dependencies to see what compatible angular versions they have. There's https://ngx-libs.com/ to help but you may have to look at the individual libraries themselves. For example ngrx so far updates in lock with angular so updating to angular 13 means also updating ngrx to version 13 along with any code migrations required.

Comment: Referred the link, and updated the versions using ex: ng update @package-name. However, migration continues to fail.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, making a huge migration from v10 - v16.  I'm going to try to uninstall all the libraries and reinstall them, since it's such a huge mess of tangled deps